# Visual Basic loop with strings and .chars

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

```
    Dim counter, len, num, tst As Integer
    Dim sentence, sen As String        
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence: ")        
    sentence = Console.ReadLine()       
    len = sentence.Length        
    num = 0
    Console.WriteLine(len)
    For counter = 0 To len - 1 Step 1
        Console.WriteLine(sentence.Chars(0))
    Next
```

I am having trouble making a loop that takes user input, then a loop from 0 to whatever length the string is, and on each line the loop prints it adds a new character, for example:
**the user inputs:**

*This is a test*

**the console would print**

```
T
Th
Thi
This
```

and so on until it prints the entire sentence the user input... If someone could help me understand whats going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do homework and I'm stuck, I've been changing things around for the last two hours. What I have so far is the console printing the same letter over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the MID function to extract part of a string. You must specify the starting position and how many characters you want to extract.

```
Console.WriteLine(Mid(sentence, 1, counter + 1))
```

Without the MID function:

```
For counter = 0 To len - 1 Step 1
        Dim chars As Integer
        For chars = 0 To counter
            Console.Write(sentence.Chars(chars))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, would it be possible to do it without a mid function?

Comment: Adding a nested FOR can be achieved without using the MID function.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your FOR loop.

```
   For counter = 1 To len
        Console.WriteLine(mid(sentence, 1, counter))
    Next
```

That should do it...

Comment: Thanks man, but that got me back to where I was in the first place, I'm trying to print it out horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: How about now?  I updated my answer that should give you what you are looking for...